# MySql/mariadb load data more 100 millon rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope you can help me I would be very grateful. I need to load a text file with more than 100 million records of which would be the ideal configuration and the storage engine for this load data(my. Cnf)

Windows que 10 server
64 Gb ram

Comment: `LOAD DATA` is probably the fastest way to get this data into a MySQL table.  Try looking into that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I almost went there as well, but the question being asked is actually around "best practices" for database sizing and storage engine.

Comment: Ah...so you think it is asking for MyISAM vs. InnoDB etc.?

Comment: Yesterday I used load data to infile with the storage and engine innob after 5 hours so I could improve this situation and because the information that arrived averaged 28 million records per month and took the first 4 months. If I go to investigate a little more and on the best practices of I would really like my knowledge on the subject is empirical and based on forums

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen de Regarding the engines always used innodb but my tables did not exceed more than 5000 records, this is new for me, and the issue is more as I must configure my. Cnf file for Best performance